# SourceTree 1ahead 1behind

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have done some changes on develop branch and committed those changes. When I wanted to push, I observed a pull request. When I tried to pull, I am getting the following error

*git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false pull --no-commit origin develop

error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).

hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.

fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge*

When I am trying to push, I am getting the following error

*git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin develop:develop

Pushing to https://radcherukuri@bitbucket.org/aerocsaccldev/hubcld-magneticcompass.git

To https://radcherukuri@bitbucket.org/aerocsaccldev/hubcld-magneticcompass.git = [up to date]      v0.1 -> v0.1

! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)

error: failed to push some refs to 'radcherukuri@bitbucket.org/aerocsaccldev/hubcld-magneticcompass.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.*

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: I'd start with this: "error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists). hint: Please, commit your changes before merging."

Answer (score 2):

This situation means that you have not concluded your merge, you have to fix the conflicts you got, follow these steps:

1. `git status`
2. Find the conflicts and fix them
3. `git commit`

Then you can `git pull`. If you got other conflicts fix them and don't forget to `git commit`.

Finally, you can `git push` all of your changes.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the develop branch on the remote got updated in the time you made your commit (this is why it's best to do all work on feature branches).

How I'd handle things is like this:

1. from your local develop branch create a new branch (`git checkout -b temp`);
2. go back to the develop branch (`git checkout develop`) and hard reset it to the remote branch (`git fetch origin` then `git reset --hard origin/develop`); note that this will remove your commit from the develop branch, but it's ok, we have it saved on the temp branch;
3. switch to the `temp` branch and rebase it on top of develop (`git rebase develop`); this way you can now either push this temp branch and create a pull request to have your change back in develop, or just cherry pick the commit from the temp branch on develop.

Comment: This answer doesn't help with the unfinished merge the OP mentioned.